# Is an OSGi service still "OSGi managed" when it's obtained by non-OSGi code?

Tags: osgi, apache-felix

As an OSGi newbie, I'm trying to wrap my head around the boundaries of the OSGi runtime. My app, which is not build on OSGi, i.e. it's not running in an OSGi container, starts an OSGi container into which we deploy OSGi bundles at run time. Some of these bundles register services. Later, in our non-OSGi code, we obtain those services and use them.

I'm having trouble wrapping my feeble mind around the OSGi boundaries here. To be specific, when I obtain a service and invoke one of its methods, can I assume that all of the subsequent execution is executing within the OSGi container (Felix)? In other words, are dependencies in that code resolved via the OSGi modularity mechanisms? Or did I lose that OSGi management because I am using the service from non-OSGi code?

If my question seems founded in obvious mistaken assumptions about OSGi, please feel free to point them out.

Answer (score 1):

Chad, to more effectively answer your question, I'd like to know a few things:
1) How exactly are you getting the service reference from an external application?
2) Is the external application a stand-alone application, or is it inside of a different container?  If so, there are ways to make that happen.

The question you pose is interesting. Lets put it into a context. Lets assume you are able to get a reference to an OSGi service from Felix by an external application.  When you use this service, you will be interacting with it via an interface.  In that interface in OSGi, you will have import statements referenced which will be used in the method signatures of the interface and also in any final attributes.  These import statements will have thier matching dependant libraries defined in your pom.xml file.

In order to use the service by an external application, you will need to publish an API ".jar" file that will contain the interface, and will reference the interfaces' dependancies. Your external application will need to use that API, and will likely have it assembled into your .war, .jar, or .ear file's lib directory.  Because of this, none of your external application's dependancies can conflict with your API dependancies.

As long as you can use the API, then you're right, none of the SPI's dependencies matter. You can use Spring 3.0.4.RELEASE in your external app and still use Spring 2.5.6.SNAPSHOT in your OSGi application.  As long as the API doesn't have any dependancies that conflict with the external application, you should be ok.  The trick here is that you need to put your interfaces into a minimal .jar file as your API, and then put your implementation details into an SPI. Your external ap will use the API, and inside OSGI, you will use both the API and SPI.

Please let me know if this helps.

Comment: I think it might help a lot  . . . but, to be frank, it's all kind of complicated so I need to check it out and do some tests.  BUt thanks for the direction.

Answer (score 0):

If you can get the service, then the dependencies are satisfied by definition, because bundles cannot provide services unless their dependencies are satisfied. Executing services on the outside doesn't really change anything.

Comment: But does this mean that all of the code inside of the service is still restricted to the osgi classloading mechanism for anything it might need to resolve?  Or is it possible that the classloader hierarchy in effect for my non-osgi code that is using the service would be used?  This is my confusion.  For instance, what if some of the classes used by the service are on the classpath of the non-osgi app, am I promised that the service code will be executing against ONLY what it can see via osgi modularity?